# strToHex ( string to its hex representation as string)

Tags: beginner, c, strings

I want to convert strings to their hex representations as strings too (like hex dump programs), for example `"abz"` to `"61627A"`.

```
char * strToHex( char * str )
{
    int length = strlen ( str );
    char * newStr = malloc( length  * 2 );
    if ( !newStr ) shutDown ( "can't alloc memory" ) ;

    for ( int x = 0; x < length; x++){
        char y = str[ x ];
        sprintf ( newStr + x * 2, "%02X", y );
    }
    return newStr;
}
```

`ShutDown` definition is omitted here, it is a function that calls `perror` and `exit()`

I designed `strToHex` to be used like

```
char * str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char * hex = strToHex(str);
printf("%s\n",hex);
//outputs : 6162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F707172737475767778797A
```

Comment: I'd be really interested to see what shutdown(char* msg) does.

Comment: In the use case that was provided, since you can effectively predict the size, I would think it would be more natural to have a string buffer and the size passed in instead of creating it dynamically.

Comment: Won't `printf()` require `hex` to have a trailing `\0` byte?

Comment: @pacmaninbw The argument name is actually "msg" as you guessed   . `void shutDown(char * msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}`

Comment: @jochen Yes, thank you, I forgot to terminate `newStr`, and I was unlucky the couple of tests that I run didn't fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Bug

As Carsten points out, you need to allocate \$(\text{length}\cdot 2)+1\$ bytes, rather than \$(\text{length}\cdot2)\$ to account for the null terminator `sprintf()` adds.

### Formatting

Most C formatting guides do not include spaces around the arguments to function calls, nor the expressions within an if-statement. For an example of a C style most C programmers would find acceptable, see OpenBSD's [`style(9)`](https://man.openbsd.org/style) manual.

I choose to associate `*` with the variable name, rather than floating between the type and name. This disambiguates the following example:

```
int *a, b;
```

Here, `a` is a pointer to an integer, but `b` is only an integer. By moving the asterisk next to the name, it makes this clearer.

```
int length = strlen ( str );
char * newStr = malloc (length * 2 );
if ( !newStr) shutDown ( "can't allocate memory" ) ;
```

Becomes:

```
int const len = strlen(str);
char *const new_str = malloc(1 + len * 2);

if (new_str == NULL) {
    shutDown("can't allocate memory");
}
```

### Error checking

Rather than calling `shutDown()` and `exit()`ing the program, you should instead return an error value which can be checked by the caller of `str_to_hex()`. Because you return a pointer, you can return `NULL` to indicate an error occurred and the caller should check `errno`.

Likewise, on some systems your program can incorrectly exit when `length == 0`. If we look at the manual page for [`malloc(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc):

> #### Return Value
>
> The malloc() and calloc() functions return a pointer to the allocated memory that is suitably aligned for any kind of variable. On error, these functions return NULL. **NULL may also be returned by a successful call to malloc() with a size of zero**, or by a successful call to calloc() with nmemb or size equal to zero.

So by returning `NULL` we account for the case where `malloc(3)` returns NULL on *success*.

```
if (new_str == NULL) {
    shutDown("can't alloc memory");
}
```

Becomes:

```
if (new_str == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}
```

If you choose, you can also check if `str` is NULL before calling `strlen()`. This is up to you, and it's not uncommon in C to ignore this case and leave it as user error.

### Looping

Use the `size_t` type in your loop rather than `int`. `size_t` is guaranteed be wide enough to hold any array index, while `int` is not.

Using `i` rather than `x` is more common for looping variables.

The `y` variable isn't needed. You can simply use `str[i]` in its place.

In terms of performance there's likely a faster option than using `sprintf()`. You should look into [`strtol(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol).

### Conclusion

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
str_to_hex(char const *const str)
{
    size_t const len = strlen(str);

    char *const new_str = malloc(1 + len * 2);

    if (new_str == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        sprintf(new_str + i * 2, "%02X", str[i]);
    }

    return new_str;
}

int
main(void)
{
    char *str = "abz";
    char *hex = str_to_hex(str);

    if (hex == NULL && strlen(str) != 0) {
        /* error ... */
    }

    printf("%s\n",hex);

    free(hex);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Won't `printf()` require `hex` to have a trailing `\0` byte?

Comment: You should allocate 2*len+1 bytes.

Comment: sprintf [adds a null terminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357068/sprintf-without-trailing-null-space-in-c#357081). @Carsten thanks, I forgot to include that, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much I'll consider every point seriously. regarding the functions definition, you wrote the return type on a separate line then on the next line you continue the function like `char * \nstr_to_hex(char const *const str)\n` is this convention has a name or reference that I can refer to ?

Comment: @Accountantم It is from the OpenBSD [manual](https://man.openbsd.org/style), the style is called BSD kernel normal form (KNF). Around the middle of manual: "The function type should be on a line by itself preceding the function."

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the most severe problem is "Insufficient target memory".

```
int length = strlen ( str );
char * newStr = malloc( length  * 2 );
```

You are allocating twice the length of `str`, which is enough for all the hex characters (two hex chars per input byte).

But `sprintf` works different: "*A terminating null character is automatically appended after the content*" (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)).

So the last call to `sprintf` will write a terminating zero byte right *after* `newStr`, into unallocated memory. This might provoke all kinds of unintended behaviour, including (but not limited to) crashes.

Comment: Yes thank you, it's a bug. I forgot to terminate `newStr`, thanks for highlighting this as it's the biggest problem in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Just one addition: like `asprintf` *vs* `snprintf`. One can effectively predict the size, so I would think it natural to have a string buffer and the size passed in instead of creating it dynamically.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* strtol */
#include <string.h> /* strlen */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <assert.h> /* assert */

/** Converts {str} to the underlying bit representation in hex, stored in
 {hex}. It may fail to compute the entire string due to {hex_size}, in which
 case the return will be less then the {str} length.
 str: A valid null-terminated string.
 hex: The output string.
 hex_size: The output string's size.
 return: The number of characters from the original that it processed. */
static size_t strToHex(const char *str, char *hex, size_t hex_size)
{
    static const char digits[0x0F] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5',
        '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F' };
    const size_t str_len = strlen(str), hex_len = hex_size - 1;
    const size_t length = str_len < hex_len / 2 ? str_len : hex_len / 2;
    const char *s = str;
    char *h = hex;
    size_t x;
    assert(str && hex);
    if(!hex_size) return 0;
    for(x = 0; x < length; x++)
        *h++ = digits[(*s & 0xF0) >> 4], *h++ = digits[*s++ & 0x0F];
    *h = '\0';
    return s - str;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", *str2 = "æôƌԹظⓐa";
    char hex[80];
    size_t ret;
    ret = strToHex(str, hex, sizeof hex);
    printf("\"%s\" -> \"%s\" (%lu.)\n", str, hex, (unsigned long)ret);
    ret = strToHex(str, hex, sizeof hex / 2);
    printf("\"%s\" -> \"%s\" (%lu.)\n", str, hex, (unsigned long)ret);
    ret = strToHex(str, hex, 0);
    printf("\"%s\" -> \"%s\" (%lu.)\n", str, hex, (unsigned long)ret);
    ret = strToHex(str2, hex, sizeof hex);
    printf("\"%s\" -> \"%s\" (%lu.)\n", str2, hex, (unsigned long)ret);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It cannot really fail if given the proper input, so this simplifies error checking a lot, especially in `C`. `malloc` and `sprintf` are pretty slow functions, comparatively, so I expect this to be faster and more robust.

Comment: Thank you very much, I like the way you documented the function, is this a known convention for documenting C code ? I also like the performance consideration that this function has over the function I posted, but I generally give easier user interfaces more priority over performance, unless I get bottlenecks. I will study your code today again with a deeper look.

Comment: The key thing here is the absence of `malloc`, which makes it much easier to use. Not that `malloc` is bad, eg, `asprintf`, but I find it makes it more complex to use properly. I like to try to code so that it's easy to put into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen, with some modifications for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I did more tests on the function today and found another Bug (shame on me), and [AFAIK on code review I can't change the original code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) in the question since it got reviews.

if there are bytes have values more than 127 it will be all displayed as `FF` by the function. To reproduce

```
char str[] = {127,0};
char * hex = strToHex(str);
printf("%s\n",hex); //pritnts 7F (NORMAL)

//now try with this
char str[] = {128,0};
char * hex = strToHex(str);
printf("%s\n",hex); //pritnts FF (BUG)
```

It appears if the function is used with non English characters because they are stored with the most significant bit is set `1` in UTF-8

### The Fix

To Fix it, replace this line

```
sprintf ( newStr + x * 2, "%02X", y );
```

with this

```
sprintf ( newStr + x * 2, "%02hhX", y ); // added hh
```

This is because `y` is of type `char` or `signed char` and the `X` specifier expects the argument to be `unsigned int` if no length is provided, so we provided length `hh` to tell the function that `X` is `unsigned char` . Check the [length table of printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

If we didn't provided `hh`, the `sprintf` function is going to promote `Y` from `signed char` to `unsigned int` and this promotion will go like this

when we defined the `str` as char and assigned the value 128 to it, it's represented as

```
1000 0000
```

The compiler thought it is -128 because it's type is *signed* char, now function `sprintf` wants to promote it to unsigned int, so to represent -128 in size of int, it will be like

```
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1000 0000
^^^^ ^^^^  ^^^^ ^^^^
```

and because we chose to show only 2 digits then we see the last 2 bytes `FF`.

more info are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464068/5407848) , and [here](https://github.com/LambdaSchool/CS-Wiki/wiki/Casting-Signed-to-Unsigned-in-C)

Comment: This is only an issue on implementations that treat `char` as signed.  If a `char` is unsigned it isn't a problem.  Other possible fixes include declaring `y` as an `unsigned char`, casting `y` to an `unsigned char` in the `sprintf` call, or masking it (`y & 0xFF`).